# A non modern theory of generalized Thom spectra

Tags: reference-request, cobordism, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

I've already posted this question on mathoverflow a few days ago and I had no reaction, I hope it is not illegal to repost it on math.stackexchange.

I'm new in the subject of stable homotopy theory, and currently trying to understand modern research on Thom spectra, like "which spectra are Thom spectra".

I know that a systematic generalization of Thom spectra is possible with the theory of $\infty$-categories, as exposed in [ABGHR] *An $\infty$-categorical approach to $R$-line bundles, $R$-module Thom spectra, and twisted $R$-homology*.

I was wondering if a geometric theory of generalized Thom spectra was possible, and if someone had a reference about that if it exists. By geometric theory I mean with topological spaces, constructing generalized Thom spaces by taking the cofiber of the projections and forming a spectrum, + a generalized Thom Pontrjagin theorem. At least I'm hoping that someting has been written about the case where the fibers are $p$-local spheres, as it is suggested in [MRS] *The Thomified Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence*.

Thank you for your help on the reference-request question.

Comment: Have you tried Rudyak's book?

Comment: Yes I have tried it, it deals with those "$\mathcal V$-objects" where $\mathcal V$ is one of the classifying spaces among $\mathcal O$, $\mathcal PL$, $\mathcal TOP$ and $\mathcal G$ where $\mathcal G$ is the colimit of $[S^n,S^n]$ . I would like to take $\mathcal V$ = the colimit of $[S^n_{(p)},S^n_{(p)}]$ for a theory of Thom spectra of $p$-local fibrations, I think this is not treated in Rudyak...

Comment: I think you mean that $\mathcal{G}$ is the colimit of $Map_{\pm1}(S^n,S^n)$ (it is a space not a set). What exactly do you you have in mind when you say '$p$-local fibration'?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant that indeed. A $p$-local fibration is a fibration the fiber of which is a $p$-local sphere. There are associated Thom spectra, and it makes it possible to realise $H\mathbb Z/p$ has a generalized Thom spectrum, associated to a $p$-local fibration over $\Omega^2S^3$: I'd like to understand the proof in full details, and for that I would like to have a reference on the generalized Thom spectra in this setting. Thanks for you help

Comment: It's ok, I found my hapiness in D. Sullivan - Geometric Topology. Localization, Periodicity, and Galois Symmetry. Thank you anyway Tyrone.